# Does robots.txt apply to files/directories only, or URLs too?

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt

I can use robots.txt to stop a folder of images/html files getting indexed. But what about dynamic pages, e.g. preventing indexing of certain WordPress pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The robots.txt syntax doesn't care about whether a page is dynamic or not: All that matters for it is the directory structure.

If you are using a permalink structure like

```
example.com/blog/year/month/slug
```

you should be able to exclude single pages like so:

```
user-agent: *
disallow: /blog/2011/09/this-is-a-test-entry
```

you could use Google's webmaster tools to verify whether that happens properly.

Remember that Wordpress stores static content like images and PDF documents in `/wp-content` - you can't block those this way unless you want to block *all* resources in that directory.